# QSWAT+ Sink category error during HRU creation

Tags: qgis, qswat

I'm trying to create a catchment model in QSWAT+ on Windows and keep getting errors during HRU creation. The process runs during the first stage of HRU creation, reading the Landuse and soil layers, but when I go to the second tab and create HRUs, it runs the process but I get the following error when it finishes:

```
CRITICAL    Internal error: routing sink category RES id 5 not found as a source
CRITICAL    Internal error: routing sink category RES id 14 not found as a source
```

I'm not sure what these errors mean or what the implications are, or how to fix them.

I created my reservoirs by adding pond and reservoir points on the outlets of water bodies during the deliniation stage. I aligned the points aligned with the edge of water bodies categorised as 'WATR' on my land use layer, within snapping distance of channels. I then set the reservoir threshold to 80% when I ran the first stage of HRU creation. This is the 2nd method provided for lake/reservoir creation in the QSWAT+ manual.

I previously tried to upload a lakes shapefile with polygons marked as ponds and reservoirs during the deliniation stage, but I kept getting a python error that would cause the plugin to crash and it would then fail to load my project in QSWAT+. Unfortunately I don't know what the python error message was and I cant find any logs saved on my drive so I don't think I can reproduce it. However, I'm not having this problem using the current method.